# get_field not displaying my custom field value

Tags: categories, custom-field, loop, advanced-custom-fields

I'm asking regarding the ACF plugin (Advanced Custom Fields)

I'm working on creating a category group that will add custom fields to the category pages. These are the fields:

[image]

They seem to work in storing the data (I can see the data is saved with an example category)

[image]

According to [the docs](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/), I'm supposed to use `get_field` in the template files to get the value of the custom field. I'm in the category.php template, and using `get_field` returns FALSE (bool).

Here is my code:

```
$sub_heading = get_field("sub_heading");
```

That should get the text that's stored in the "sub_heading" custom field, but instead it just returns FALSE (bool).

I also tried

```
$sub_heading = get_field("sub_heading", $cat->term_id)
```

The category page is displaying the category properly, and giving me the title and the description, but nothing is being returned from `get_field`.

Answer (score 5):

Nevermind, I figured this out.

The id needs to be "category_" and then the ID.

So the code is:

```
$sub_heading = get_field("sub_heading", "category_" . $cat->term_id);
```

Comment: can you mark this question answered?